# 16.04.1 LTS glibcxx 3.4.21 not defined

Tags: apt, glibc

`apt-get` often gets this error:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4 21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

File usr/bin/do-release-upgrade line 11 in module.

File usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py line 25 in module

File usr/line/python3/dist-packages/apt/**init**.py Iine 23 in module apt_pkg

What does that mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this was fixed by looking at old posts.

Booting up when holding shift key allows you to go into grub menu.  From there I repaired packages.

Now apt get works fine.